# Model associations for a contest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm new to rails and working on an app that has the following situation:

Users have skills (e.g rafting, dancing)
Users participate in contests
Contest measures multiple skills
At the end of each contest, each user gets a score (e.g dancing: 5, rafting: 4)

Whats the best way to model this ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This got nasty :s At the end I was actually not sure if this is the right way

```
class Skill < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :skill_scores
  has_many :user_skills
end

class UserSkill < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :skill
end

class SkillScore < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :contest
  belongs_to :skill
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :skills
  has_many :contests, :through => :contest_participations
  has_many :skill_scores
end

class Contest < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users, :through => :contest_participations
  has_many :skill_scores
end

class ContestParticipation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :contest
end
```